# Resizing Components and Font with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, font-size, miglayout

i'm pretty new to Layout Managers and i have absolutely no idea how to resize the Font-Size automatically with the `MigLayout` Manager. I have already managed to resize the components with the grow and fill constraint, but I don't seem to get the font-size to change with the size of the components. How do i do this?

Here my few code lines:

```
public class Projekte {
public Projekte()
{
    main();
}
public static void main() {

    JFrame projekte = new JFrame();
    projekte.setBounds(100, 100,1080,1900);
    projekte.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    projekte.setTitle("Testframe");
    projekte.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
    projekte.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][][][grow,fill][][][][]", "[][][][][][][][][][][grow,fill][][]"));

        JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("Test");
        projekte.getContentPane().add(lblTest, "cell 4 10,alignx trailing");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        projekte.getContentPane().add(textField, "cell 5 10");
        textField.setColumns(10);
        JLabel lblTest_2 = new JLabel("Test_2");
        projekte.getContentPane().add(lblTest_2, "cell 6 10,alignx trailing");
        JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField();
        projekte.getContentPane().add(textField_2, "cell 7 10");
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        JLabel lblTest_3 = new JLabel("Test_3");
        projekte.getContentPane().add(lblTest_3, "cell 4 11,alignx trailing");
        JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
        projekte.getContentPane().add(textField_3, "cell 5 11");
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

I think it is quite easy, but I don't seem to find the solution, maybe you can help.

Comment: `public static void main()` Huh? Why not throw in a `String[]` as the argument (and wrap that code in a Swing EDT), add the imports and make it a [mcve]?

Comment: i don't know what you mean, the code is easy and understandable and exactly shows my problem. if you run this code you will see that the Textfields are resizing with the frame, but the font size does not, the form isn't finished anyways, this are just my first steps, but if automatically resizing the font-size doesn't work, then i can cancel working with this Layout Manager.

Comment: `I don't seem to get the font-size to change with the size of the components.` - the font size doesn't change. Each component determines its own preferred size based on the Font, Border, text etc of the component. Then the layout manager uses this information to position the components on the frame. If you want a bigger font, then you need to use the setFont(...) method on each component.

Comment: how do i do that? The font has to be resized dynamically when resizing the frame, but i don't know how to call the Resize Method and how to implement the font-size so that it doesn't look weird

Answer (score 0):

Font have attributes, but any of them relate to layout - you can manually scale font with some parameter using *deriveFont(float size)*
- creates a new Font object by replicating the current Font object and applying a new size to it.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
float scale = screenWidth/1000;
label.getFont().deriveFont(scale);
```